# Exception when calling SDL_RenderCopy

Tags: c++, exception, rendering, sdl, access-violation

I'm relatively new to C++ and I am learning it using SDL 2.0. I have encountered the following error when trying to draw a sprite using my **Sprite** class:

Exception thrown at 0x000000006C793659 (SDL2.dll) in SDDDDL2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The following code is a stripped down version of the involved code in my **Sprite** class:

```
public:
SDL_Texture *image = NULL;
SDL_Rect rect;

void SetTexture(SDL_Texture *texture) 
{
    image = texture;
    rect.x = 100; rect.y = 100; rect.w = 64; rect.h = 64;
}

void DrawSprite(SDL_Renderer *renderer) 
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,image,NULL,&rect); //Calling this causes the
    //error
}
```

And the key code in my main game class "Game.cpp"

```
Sprite *testSprite = NULL;
SDL_Texture *testTex = NULL;

void LoadContent() 
{
    SDL_Surface *bmpSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("sprite.bmp");
    testTex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, bmpSurface);
    testSprite = &Sprite(Vector2(100,100),Vector2(50,50)); // Just the 
    //constuctor, this is not affecting the issue
    testSprite->SetTexture(testTex);
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmpSurface);
}

void Draw () 
{
    testSprite->DrawSprite(renderer); // Get the error when calling this
}
```

I know through testing that it is indeed the texture being passed into the SDL_RenderCopy function (**image**) that is causing the issue, as this does not happen if I call the function in Game.cpp file using the "testTex" image.

I also know that the texture used in the SDL_RenderCopy function is not **NULL**, as I used null checks before calling SDL_RenderCopy, and it called anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Fara Importanta! Just when I didn't think it was the constructor causing the issue... Using the "new" keyword seemed to work perfectly, but causes an error on the vectors (they are structs if that has something to do with it) so I'm leaving them alone, but they work fine anyway.

Comment: Glad my hint fixed it. Copied my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this line: `testSprite = &Sprite(Vector2(100,100), Vector2(50,50));`

The address value that `testSprite` gets assigned is invalid as soon as `LoadContent()` returns.

Replace it with e.g. `testSprite = new Sprite(Vector2(100,100),Vector2(50,50));` and re-run.